# Mysql Concat not null value

Tags: mysql

Guy I'm trying to concat not null value from a list column.
i don't need that null in value

```
SELECT Emp_fname, Call_number, concat( Aud_name,Mag_name,Boo_name) as name 
FROM manage left JOIN call_number ON manage.Man_Call_id = call_number.Call_id 
left JOIN book_ ON call_number.Call_id = book_.Boo_id 
left JOIN employee_ ON manage.Man_emp_id = employee_.Emp_id 
left JOIN audiovisual_ ON call_number.Call_id = audiovisual_.Aud_Call_id 
left join magzine_ ON call_number.Call_id = magzine_.Mag_Call_id
```

[not concat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDtTp.png)
[concat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzCg5.png)

Comment: PLease add you query here.

Comment: SELECT Emp_fname, Call_number,concat( Aud_name,Mag_name,Boo_name) as name
FROM manage
left JOIN call_number ON manage.Man_Call_id = call_number.Call_id
left JOIN book_ ON call_number.Call_id = book_.Boo_id
left JOIN employee_ ON manage.Man_emp_id = employee_.Emp_id
left JOIN audiovisual_ ON call_number.Call_id = audiovisual_.Aud_Call_id
left join magzine_ ON call_number.Call_id = magzine_.Mag_Call_id

Comment: What is your question, and can you show us some sample data?

Comment: What are `Aud_name,Mag_name,Boo_name` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `CONCAT` function, if passed even a single `NULL` value, will just return `NULL` as a result.  If you want to ignore possible `NULL` values when calling `CONCAT` with a list of columns, then you may use `COALESCE`.  Here is one version of your query which would completely ignore `NULL`:

```
SELECT
    Emp_fname,
    Call_number,
    CONCAT(COALESCE(Aud_name, ''), COALESCE(Mag_name, ''), COALESCE(Boo_name, '')) AS name
FROM manage
...
```

If you don't want to replace the nulls with empty string, you may use any string replacement you wish.